# Can I create an Athena table from my AWS account for a different AWS account, assuming permissions are set?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to give a customer access to data in my account, but building a table around my s3 bucket requires additional overhead as the number of partitions are increasing overtime. In my account, I have a lambda that automatically handles this by dropping/creating Athena tables with the necessary partition projections. I would like to have this same lambda create/drop an Athena table on another AWS account, not owned by me, is this possible? I know I could give each team access to my Athena table, but then all querying costs are accrued by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback I received on the issues I was encountering, I ended up not needing to create/drop tables on another AWS account and instead used Athena's [`ALTER TABLE SET`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-set-tblproperties.html) query to properly change the partition projections needed for my Athena table (via the execution of a lambda). Customers are required to do the same for their tables that rely on our s3 data.

Note: If you choose to go this route, make sure that the code that runs the `ALTER TABLE SET` handles the race condition associated with setting the properties of the table rather than appending to them. (i.e If a property value is equal to **XYZ** and the code responsible for executing the query runs in parallel (via multiple lambda invocations or some sort of parallelism), then you may run into the case that process **A** attempts to add value **T** to **XYZ** while process **B** attempts to add value **C** resulting in either **XYZT** or **XYZC** instead of the expected **XYZTC**)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to give a customer access to data in my account, but building a table around my s3 bucket requires additional overhead as the number of partitions are increasing overtime.

If I'm not mistaken, you won't have to manage partitions of your Athena/Glue table if you have [Partition Projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) set up. So if your customer has the right permissions for accessing objects in your S3 bucket, they should be able to run queries via a table defined in their account.

> I would like to have this same lambda create/drop an Athena table on another AWS account, not owned by me, is this possible?

Yes, this is certainly possible as long as the correct permissions for creating/deleting tables in Glue are granted.

Comment: Yea the issue was that as my lambdas run they discover new partitions that could not have been known / are not included in the initial partition projections. We ended up not going the route specified in this question, but thanks for your response regardless.